# WebRTC with Google Home Camera

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to get the Google Home Camera working with WebRTC.

GetCameraStream request:

```
{"inputs":[{"context":{"locale_country":"US","locale_language":"en"},"intent":"action.devices.EXECUTE","payload":{"commands":[{"devices":[{"id":"xxx"}],"execution":[{"command":"action.devices.commands.GetCameraStream","params":{"StreamToChromecast":true,"SupportedStreamProtocols":["webrtc"]}}]}]}}],"requestId":"8537385264491436978"}
```

Response

```
{"status":200,"headers":{"content-type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"body":{"requestId":"8537385264491436978","payload":{"commands":[{"ids":["64971cac94b0e2a6240518ad"],"status":"SUCCESS","states":{"online":true,"cameraStreamSignalingUrl":"https://xxxx/signaling/answer","cameraStreamIceServers":"","cameraStreamOffer":"","cameraStreamAuthToken":""}}]}}}
```

After that I expect Google Home to send the SDP offer request to `"https://xxxx/signaling/answer"` endpoint but it's not.

However, I am seeing Google Home calls `"https://xxxx/signaling/answer"` when the user close the google home app screen.

```
{"action":"end"}
```

In the Google Cloud Logs. I can see

```
    {
.....
      "jsonPayload": {
        "clientUpdateLog": {
          "deviceType": "action.devices.types.CAMERA",
          "camerastreamProtocol": "webrtc",
          "camerastreamExecutionUpdate": {
            "streamTerminationTime": "2023-06-30T01:13:01.012600898Z",
            "webrtcSignalingInitiationTime": "2023-06-30T01:13:01.010277032Z",
            "status": "EMPTY_SDP",
            "testPartnerFacingDebugString": "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ASTWebRTCConnectionDomain error -1015.)"
          },
          "httpRequestId": "15739477561818846648"
        }
      },
      ..
    }
```

just wondering what's `EMPTY_SDP` means here since `cameraStreamOffer` in the response is optional according to [Google Home documentation](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/camerastream#device-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you need a Google Home Chromecast or Nest device to test. The Google Home app's camera preview is in beta and the way it works is different.

hope this helps someone else.